# Put a lot of data from an array into usable data?

Tags: php, arrays, api

Okay hi guys,

I've been messing with my little side project today (had some great help on something I was stuck on & I've a new little issue I cant seem to get my head around. I'm sure its me just being stupid.

So basically, I've a lot of data from a game (LoL) but I'm not sure how to structure this so it's readable, am I going to have to put it into an array and explode the contents? If so how?

This is what I've got that's pulling the data from an API:

```
<?php
                $summoner_name = 'amphios';
                $summoner_id = 21554735;

                $profile = new riotapi('euw');

                $summonername = $profile->getSummonerByName($summoner_name);
                print_r($summonername);

                $summonerstats = $profile->getStats($summoner_id, 'ranked');
                print_r($summonerstats);

                $getsummoner = $profile->getSummoner($summoner_id, 'name');
                print_r($getsummoner);

            ?>
```

And this is what it's showing (sorry for the big wall of text):

```
{"id":21554735,"name":"Amphios","profileIconId":588,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1390725829000}{"summonerId":21554735,"modifyDate":1390725829000,"champions":[{"id":89,"name":"Leona","stats":{"totalSessionsPlayed":1,"totalSessionsLost":1,"totalSessionsWon":0,"totalChampionKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":27547,"totalDamageTaken":21722,"mostChampionKillsPerSession":0,"totalMinionKills":17,"totalDoubleKills":0,"totalTripleKills":0,"totalQuadraKills":0,"totalPentaKills":0,"totalUnrealKills":0,"totalDeathsPerSession":6,"totalGoldEarned":7288,"mostSpellsCast":0,"totalTurretsKilled":0,"totalPhysicalDamageDealt":6559,"totalMagicDamageDealt":20987,"totalFirstBlood":0,"totalAssists":12,"maxChampionsKilled":0,"maxNumDeaths":6}},{"id":254,"name":"Vi","stats":{"totalSessionsPlayed":1,"totalSessionsLost":0,"totalSessionsWon":1,"totalChampionKills":2,"totalDamageDealt":101554,"totalDamageTaken":18470,"mostChampionKillsPerSession":2,"totalMinionKills":122,"totalDoubleKills":0,"totalTripleKills":0,"totalQuadraKills":0,"totalPentaKills":0,"totalUnrealKills":0,"totalDeathsPerSession":1,"totalGoldEarned":11358,"mostSpellsCast":0,"totalTurretsKilled":0,"totalPhysicalDamageDealt":81674,"totalMagicDamageDealt":18995,"totalFirstBlood":0,"totalAssists":15,"maxChampionsKilled":2,"maxNumDeaths":1}},{"id":103,"name":"Ahri","stats":{"totalSessionsPlayed":5,"totalSessionsLost":2,"totalSessionsWon":3,"totalChampionKills":33,"totalDamageDealt":583292,"totalDamageTaken":86957,"mostChampionKillsPerSession":10,"totalMinionKills":798,"totalDoubleKills":2,"totalTripleKills":0,"totalQuadraKills":0,"totalPentaKills":0,"totalUnrealKills":0,"totalDeathsPerSession":22,"totalGoldEarned":55637,"mostSpellsCast":0,"totalTurretsKilled":0,"totalPhysicalDamageDealt":88954,"totalMagicDamageDealt":323163,"totalFirstBlood":0,"totalAssists":38,"maxChampionsKilled":10,"maxNumDeaths":7}},{"id":64,"name":"LeeSin","stats":{"totalSessionsPlayed":2,"totalSessionsLost":0,"totalSessionsWon":2,"totalChampionKills":15,"totalDamageDealt":283794,"totalDamageTaken":47208,"mostChampionKillsPerSession":8,"totalMinionKills":324,"totalDoubleKills":3,"totalTripleKills":1,"totalQuadraKills":0,"totalPentaKills":0,"totalUnrealKills":0,"totalDeathsPerSession":7,"totalGoldEarned":26702,"mostSpellsCast":0,"totalTurretsKilled":2,"totalPhysicalDamageDealt":179409,"totalMagicDamageDealt":102365,"totalFirstBlood":0,"totalAssists":29,"maxChampionsKilled":8,"maxNumDeaths":4}},{"id":81,"name":"Ezreal","stats":{"totalSessionsPlayed":1,"totalSessionsLost":0,"totalSessionsWon":1,"totalChampionKills":10,"totalDamageDealt":168089,"totalDamageTaken":27079,"mostChampionKillsPerSession":10,"totalMinionKills":165,"totalDoubleKills":0,"totalTripleKills":0,"totalQuadraKills":0,"totalPentaKills":0,"totalUnrealKills":0,"totalDeathsPerSession":8,"totalGoldEarned":15275,"mostSpellsCast":0,"totalTurretsKilled":3,"totalPhysicalDamageDealt":131121,"totalMagicDamageDealt":34756,"totalFirstBlood":0,"totalAssists":17,"maxChampionsKilled":10,"maxNumDeaths":8}},{"id":105,"name":"Fizz","stats":{"totalSessionsPlayed":1,"totalSessionsLost":1,"totalSessionsWon":0,"totalChampionKills":3,"totalDamageDealt":80294,"totalDamageTaken":21753,"mostChampionKillsPerSession":3,"totalMinionKills":114,"totalDoubleKills":0,"totalTripleKills":0,"totalQuadraKills":0,"totalPentaKills":0,"totalUnrealKills":0,"totalDeathsPerSession":7,"totalGoldEarned":9389,"mostSpellsCast":0,"totalTurretsKilled":0,"totalPhysicalDamageDealt":19029,"totalMagicDamageDealt":60293,"totalFirstBlood":0,"totalAssists":12,"maxChampionsKilled":3,"maxNumDeaths":7}},{"id":2,"name":"Olaf","stats":{"totalSessionsPlayed":1,"totalSessionsLost":0,"totalSessionsWon":1,"totalChampionKills":5,"totalDamageDealt":183508,"totalDamageTaken":34625,"mostChampionKillsPerSession":5,"totalMinionKills":211,"totalDoubleKills":0,"totalTripleKills":0,"totalQuadraKills":0,"totalPentaKills":0,"totalUnrealKills":0,"totalDeathsPerSession":7,"totalGoldEarned":14095,"mostSpellsCast":0,"totalTurretsKilled":3,"totalPhysicalDamageDealt":117878,"totalMagicDamageDealt":37453,"totalFirstBlood":0,"totalAssists":8,"maxChampionsKilled":5,"maxNumDeaths":7}},{"id":1,"name":"Annie","stats":{"totalSessionsPlayed":6,"totalSessionsLost":2,"totalSessionsWon":4,"totalChampionKills":49,"totalDamageDealt":905226,"totalDamageTaken":122780,"mostChampionKillsPerSession":12,"totalMinionKills":1045,"totalDoubleKills":5,"totalTripleKills":1,"totalQuadraKills":0,"totalPentaKills":0,"totalUnrealKills":0,"totalDeathsPerSession":45,"totalGoldEarned":83361,"mostSpellsCast":0,"totalTurretsKilled":5,"totalPhysicalDamageDealt":84761,"totalMagicDamageDealt":813322,"totalFirstBlood":0,"totalAssists":53,"maxChampionsKilled":12,"maxNumDeaths":12}},{"id":0,"name":"Combined","stats":{"totalSessionsPlayed":18,"totalSessionsLost":6,"totalSessionsWon":12,"totalChampionKills":117,"killingSpree":60,"totalDamageDealt":2333304,"totalDamageTaken":380594,"mostChampionKillsPerSession":12,"totalMinionKills":2796,"totalDoubleKills":10,"totalTripleKills":2,"totalQuadraKills":0,"totalPentaKills":0,"totalUnrealKills":0,"totalDeathsPerSession":103,"totalGoldEarned":223105,"mostSpellsCast":0,"totalTurretsKilled":13,"totalPhysicalDamageDealt":709385,"totalMagicDamageDealt":1411334,"totalNeutralMinionsKilled":234,"totalFirstBlood":0,"totalAssists":184,"totalHeal":26727,"maxLargestKillingSpree":7,"maxLargestCriticalStrike":769,"maxChampionsKilled":12,"maxNumDeaths":12,"maxTimePlayed":3149,"maxTimeSpentLiving":1666,"normalGamesPlayed":0,"rankedSoloGamesPlayed":0,"rankedPremadeGamesPlayed":0,"botGamesPlayed":0}}]}{"summoners":[{"id":21554735,"name":"Amphios"}]}
```

I'd like to be able to use a lot of this data, and have them in a sort of $api_data['username'] and $api_data['level'] and so on, or a better way.. I'm still getting used to large amounts of data like this.

Comment: could use json encoding using then decoding the json server side would give you a usable array to play with your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_decode` function for converting your SJON string into PHP array:

```
$api_data = json_decode($getsummoner);
```

Comment: Okay that's actually really good, so once I've got it in a PHP array I can explode that and use specific parts right?

Although I'm not sure how I'm echoing out specific parts of this array.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `PHP` [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) function like this;

```
$json = '{"id":21554735,"name":"Amphios","profileIconId":588,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1390725829000}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<xmp>".print_r($arr, true)."</xmp>";  // Display the contents of $arr.
echo "Name is {$arr['name']}";              // Display the contents of $arr['name'].
```

The above will output the following;

```
Array
(
    [id] => 21554735
    [name] => Amphios
    [profileIconId] => 588
    [summonerLevel] => 30
    [revisionDate] => 1390725829000
)
Name is Amphios
```